# How can I inject a newline when a std::ostream object is std::flush'ed?

Tags: c++, std, c++20

How can I minimally wrap a `std::ofstream` so that any call to `sync` (`std::flush`) gets turned into a call to `std::endl`.

(everything below is an answer to the question "why would you do that?" and is not relevant to the above question)

---

I have an application which contains a custom `std::ostream` implementation (which wraps around zmq), let's call it `zmq_stream`.

This `zmq_stream` also internally implements a custom `streambuffer`, and works very nicely.

One of the motivations of this design is that in my unit tests, I can simply swap out the `zmq_stream` in my unit tests with a regular old `std::ostringstream` and test the results, completely hiding out the network layer.

One of the features of the application itself is to redirect application output to a file or stdout via a command line flag.

Once again, using a basic switch at startup, I can pass either `zmq_stream`, `std::ofstream` or plain old `std::cout` to my main loop.

This is accomplished something like this:

```
std::ostream* out;
switch(cond)
{
  case 1:
    out = &std::cout;
    break;
  case 2:
    out = new ofstream("file");
    break;
  case 3:
    out = new zmq_stream(method, endpoints);
    break;
}

main_loop(out);
```

The usage of `zmq_stream` is as follows:

```cpp
zmq_stream out(method, endpoints);

out << "do something " << 42 << " or other";
out << "and another" << std::flush; // <- full constructed buffer is sent over the network
```

**Note:** it is by design that I use `std::flush` and not `std::endl` when *flushing* to the network. I do not wish to append a newline to all of my network transmissions. As such, all network outputs by the application use `std::flush` and not `std::endl` and changing this is not the correct answer.

**Question:** while for testing purposes, everything works as expected, for the `std::cout` and `std::ofstream` options, I'd like to be able to *inject* a newline when `std::flush` is called, so that my network transmissions can be separated into newlines on `stdout`. This would allow me to pipe them onto the standard posix suite of tooling...

Without this injection, there is no way to determine (aside from timing) where the network boundaries are.

I'm looking for the most minimal possible override here so that I don't have to write out a bunch of new classes. Ideally, overriding the `sync()` virtual method so that it calls `overflow('\n');` and then calls base `sync()`.

However, this is proving to be much more challenging than I expected, so I'm wondering if I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: for `std` streams it is `std::endl` that adds a new line and calls `flush`. Just do the same with your `zmq_stream`

Comment: Switch to using `std::endl`?  That adds a newline and flushes the stream.

Comment: This breaks the semantics: I don't want to send newlines over the network. I want to flush to network without a newline.

Comment: `zmq_stream` is a class you wrote? Then you can add an overload that intercepts `std::flush` (or `std::endl` would work as well)

Comment: `zmq_stream` works - in all conditions - as expected. The system works correctly in all conditions. I would just like that when I'm *redirecting* my output to stdout, flushes also get a newline.

Comment: Maybe work the other way around, do send a "\n", but filter that out for normal use?

Comment: it is `zmq_stream` that redirects to the stream, right? You write that you want to add a new line in `out << "and another" << std::flush;` when `out` is a `zmq_stream` (and redirects to a stream) but at the same time you say that `zmq_stream` needs no modification. I am confused

Comment: how do you decide which pointer to call delete on?

Comment: @PepijnKramer that was the initial implementation: it's too bloated and bug prone. This version works much better but for this tiny niggly point which is that I want to get the ability to pipe this into `awk`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: the application writes to a `std::ostream`, it has no knowledge of what the underlying stream is. `zmq_stream` doesn't "redirect", it is simply one of the three possible backing streams (file, string or zmq). The goal is to encapsulate the file stream with an extremely thin wrapper and pass that modified stream to the application.

Comment: Yes I agree. What you have is cleaner. But the flush will not become part of the stream data so you don't have any marker to know where to insert newlines.

Comment: `zmq_stream` is a class you wrote? Why is it not an option to make `zmq_stream` intercept `std::endl` and turn it into a plain `std::flush` ?

Comment: or wrap the file stream, intercept `std::flush` and turn it into a `std::endl`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: your last comment is the question: how do I wrap the file stream. `zmq_stream` is not at all in play here.

Comment: "`zmq_stream` is not at all in play here"  most of your question talks about `zmq_stream`, but well, maybe I undertood something of what you are asking

Comment: Maybe do it the other way round? Create an object that when sent to a steam either flushes or adds a new line and flushes then use that object in place of `std::flush`?

Comment: Notice that flushing might happen without explicit call to `std::flush`(neither `std::endl`). "full buffer" might also do a flush.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial solution I wrote doesn't work because it is a compile time solution and I can't switch on it without re-implementing inheritance (so that the `main_loop` function gets a base class as a parameter).

Instead, here's the answer to original problem implemented in what appears to be the most minimal way possible.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

typedef std::ostringstream zmq_stream;

template <class T>
class newline_injector_streambuf: public std::basic_streambuf<T> {
public:
    using int_type = typename std::basic_streambuf<T>::int_type;
    newline_injector_streambuf(std::basic_streambuf<T>& dest) : sink(dest) {}

protected:

    virtual int_type sync() override { overflow('\n'); return sink.pubsync(); }
    virtual int_type overflow(int_type c) override { return sink.sputc(c); }

    std::basic_streambuf<T>& sink;
};

template <class T>
struct newline_injector_stream : public std::basic_ostream<typename T::char_type> {
    newline_injector_streambuf<typename T::char_type> buf;
    newline_injector_stream(T* file) : buf(*file->rdbuf())
    {
        std::basic_ostream<typename T::char_type>::rdbuf(&buf);
    }
};

void test(std::ostream& out)
{
    out << std::setfill('x') << std::setw(10) << "" << std::flush;
    out << "Hello, world!" << std::flush << "asdf" << std::endl;
}

int main() {

    newline_injector_stream out1(&std::cout);
    newline_injector_stream out2(new std::ofstream("test.output", std::ios::out | std::ios::ate));

    test(std::cout);
    test(out1);
    test(out2);

    return 0;
}
```

---

This is the solution that was devised thanks to @463035818-is-not-a-number's initial answer:

```cpp
    struct zmq_stream;
    template<typename T>
    struct output_device {
        T& output;

        output_device(T& backing_stream) : output(backing_stream){}

        template <typename U>
        output_device& operator<<(const U& u)
        {
            output << u;
            return *this;
        }

        output_device& operator<<(std::ostream& (*f)(std::ostream&)) {

          if constexpr (!std::is_same<T, zmq_stream>::value)
            if (f == &std::flush<std::ostream::char_type,std::ostream::traits_type>)
                output << "\n";
            output << f;
            return *this;
        }
    };

// Usage:

int main()
{
   /* prelude code */
   auto out1 = output_device(std::cout);
   auto out2 = output_device(std::ofstream("filename"));
   auto out3 = output_device(zmq_stream(method, endpoints));

   out1 << "foo" << std::flush << "bar"; // results in foo\nbar
   out2 << "foo" << std::flush << "bar"; // results in foo\nbar
   out3 << "foo" << std::flush << "bar"; // results in foobar

}

template <class T>
class separator: public std::basic_streambuf<T> {
public:
    using int_type = typename std::basic_streambuf<T>::int_type;
    using char_type = typename std::basic_streambuf<T>::char_type;
    using traits_type = typename std::basic_streambuf<T>::traits_type;

    separator(std::basic_streambuf<T> *dest) : sink(dest) {}
protected:

    virtual int_type sync() override {
        if (nullptr == sink)
            return 1;
        //std::basic_streambuf<T>::overflow('\n');
        overflow('\n');
        return sink->pubsync();
    }

    virtual int_type overflow(int_type c) override {
        if (sink == nullptr)
            return 1;
        return sink->sputc(c);
    }

    std::basic_streambuf<T> *sink = nullptr;
};

template <class T> struct newline_injector_stream : public std::basic_ostream<T> {
    separator<T> buf;
public:
    newline_injector_stream(std::basic_ostream<T> &file) : buf(file.rdbuf())
    {
        std::basic_ostream<T>::rdbuf(&buf);
    }
};
```

The `main_loop` function signature now goes from taking a `std::ostream*` type to a `output_device&` type.